# How to define classes & interfaces in Java for a special "multiple inheritance" situation

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

Given a standard class which I cannot change (greenfoot Actor; caveat: I am not familiar with either java or greenfoot), I want to create two subclasses which represent transportable goods and transporting means.

The problem appears when a transporting means, such as a bike, is small enough to be a transportable good.

```
class Transportation extends Actor {...}
class Truck extends Transportation {...}
interface Transportable {...}
class Container extends Actor implements Transportable {...}
class Bike extends Transportation implements Transportable {...}
```

Now if I want to define methods to load/unload goods, in class `Transportation`, what shall be the class of the parameter?

```
void load (Transportable goods) {
    :
    /* not exactly sure about call of getworld(); it returns the "world" */
    World.getWorld().removeObject(goods) <- this is where an Actor is needed
    :
}
```

For bookkeeping in the greenfoot world (i.e., which objects are "inside the world", meaning outside of any `Transportation`), I need to call a method on `goods` inside `load` which requires an `Actor` - and the compiler rightfully tells me that `Transportable` objects are not `Actor`s.

But interfaces (`Transportable`) cannot inherit from classes (`Actor`).

The solutions I have seen on SO say to make the top class (`Actor`, in this  case) have an associated interface, but what do I do when I do not control the top class?

EDIT: added more code in `load()` as requested; added `class Truck`

Comment: If I was you, I would never directly extend Actor. I would make a class called `TransportableActor` who would implement `Transportable` and extend `Actor`. All of my classes would then inherit from this. It will effectively wrap `Actor` to get the functionality you want

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to call Actor methods on goods inside load" ? Please include code example to indicate the failure path.

Comment: @IanGabes I agree not to fiddle with Actor. What I also would not want is to create a `TransportableActor` and make all classes inherit from it. After all, a `Truck` (I added this class to the post) is not transportable (in our little world), only the `Bike` should be.

Comment: @Harshit I've added the call which triggers the error to the code. Basically, the greenfoot World object can only remove Actors from itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to shuffle around some of your classes and create new interfaces.

```
class Actor {
 // Use Greenfoot Actor class instead of this one
}

interface ITransportation {

    public void load(Transportable goods);
}

class Transportation extends Actor implements ITransportation{

    @Override
    public void load(Transportable goods) {

    }
}

class Truck extends Transportation{

}

interface ITransportable {

}

class Transportable extends Actor implements ITransportable {

}
class Container extends Transportable {

}

class HybridGood implements ITransportable, ITransportation {

    private Transportation transportation;
    private Transportable transportable;

    @Override
    public void load(Transportable goods) {
        transportation.load(goods);
    }
}
class Bike extends HybridGood {

}
```

With this approach, you will be able to

- Share the common functionality of Transportation and Transportable
  type in HybridGoods class.
- You can access `Actor` type in load/unload method.